# Activating autocommit in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I do the following statment to activate auto commit in my sql server 2008

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
```

but i want to know when the commit happen ?after what statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but i want to know when the commit happen ?after what statement?

When  `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF`, and if you have not started a transaction using the statement `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, each individual statement is committed once they are complete. you do not need to issue a `COMMIT`

you can refer to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx) for `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS`